# Draw graph of $x^2+2y^2≤1$

Tags: geometry

Can anyone help to draw the graph of equation given as

$x^2+2y^2≤1$ .
I ended up confused whether this is the equation of an ellipse or a circle, since when i divide the whole by 2 its nit equal to = 1 as ellipse's equation required..please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: It's an ellipse, together with its interior.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{x^2}{1}+\frac{y^2}{(1/2)} \le 1$. This is an ellipse with major axis as $x$ axis and its interior points.

Comment: Or even $\frac{x^2}{1^2}+\frac{y^2}{(1/\sqrt{2})^2} \le 1$

Answer (score 0):

A disk is the locus of the points at bounded Euclidean distance from a point, and its implicit equation has the form

$$d((x,y), (a,b))\le c$$
or 
$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2\le c^2$$ where the center is $(a,b)$ and the radius $c$.

If you expand,

$$x^2+y^2-2ax-2bx\le c^2-a^2-b^2.$$

When the center is the origin,

$$x^2+y^2\le c^2.$$

You observe that the coefficients of $x^2$ and $y^2$ are equal, and this remains true even if you multiply the whole equation by a constant.

You can conclude.

---

**Addendum:**

You also notice that the LHS is lacking an $xy$ term. This is a required condition to have a circle. Indeed, for example

$$x^2+\frac13xy+y^2\le1$$ represents a filled ellipse.